# Popup slide of galleries

Tags: media, views, javascript

I need to create a slide in popup where the user can list the galleries.

In short, the left and right arrows is navigation for previous and next gallery (as well as numbers for navigation), each gallery has a number of images that can be changed by clicking on the thumbnail image.

My idea is to create a content type for the gallery, and then using Views Slideshow to list only body of that content type. Is such a thing possible? Could there be another way in which this can be done?

Any suggestion is welcome...

Comment: you can do it with views slideshow module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is step by step solution that I use to get this done:

1. Create new content type with image field
2. Install [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) and [View Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) modules
3. Create new View of type Slideshow
4. Add image field from created content type in View, than set 'Slideshow' for 'Formatter' of that field and choose settings that you want for slideshow
5. That's it, you have slideshow of images inside slidedeshow...